# Magento 1.9 Adminhtml Form Block not visible

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin, adminform

This question is asked for many times, but none of the solution worked for me. I tried referring core modules to correct the errors in my config files, but it helped me little. Following are the code snippets:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Package_OriginalPricing>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Package_OriginalPricing>
    </modules>

    <!-- Global Configuration Starts -->
    <global>

        <helpers> <!-- Helpers -->
            <originalpricing>
                <class>Package_OriginalPricing_Helper</class>
            </originalpricing>
        </helpers>

        <blocks> <!-- Blocks -->
            <originalpricing>
                <class>Package_OriginalPricing_Block</class>
            </originalpricing>
        </blocks>

        <models>

            <originalpricing>
                <class>Package_OriginalPricing_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>originalpricing_resource</resourceModel>
            </originalpricing>

            <originalpricing_resource>

                <class>Package_OriginalPricing_Model_Resource</class>

                <entities>
                    <csvprice>
                        <table>originalpricing_csvprice</table>
                    </csvprice>
                </entities>

            </originalpricing_resource>

        </models>

        <resources>

            <originalpricing_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Package_OriginalPricing</module>
                </setup>
            </originalpricing_setup>

            <originalpricing_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </originalpricing_write>

            <originalpricing_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </originalpricing_read>

        </resources>

    </global>
    <!-- !! Global Configuration -->

    <!-- Admin Configuration Starts -->
    <admin>
        <!-- Routing Configuration Starts -->
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <originalpricing before="Mage_Adminhtml">Package_OriginalPricing_Adminhtml</originalpricing>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
        <!-- !! Routing Configuration -->
    </admin>
    <!-- !! Admin Configuration -->

    <!-- Adminhtml Configuration Starts -->
    <adminhtml>
        <!-- Layouts Configuration Starts -->
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <originalpricing>
                    <file>originalpricing.xml</file>
                </originalpricing>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <!-- !! Layouts Configuration -->

        <!-- Menu Configuration Starts -->
        <menu>
            <catalog>
                <children>
                    <!-- Parent menu -->
                    <originalpricing module="originalpricing" translate="title">

                        <title>Original Price CSV</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>

                        <children> <!-- Child menu -->
                            <index translate="title"> <!-- Assign menu -->
                                <title>Upload CSV</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <action>adminhtml/originalpricing</action>
                            </index>

                            <removeproducts translate="title"> <!-- Remove menu -->
                                <title>Remove CSV</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                <action>adminhtml/originalpricing/removeproducts</action>
                            </removeproducts>
                        </children>

                    </originalpricing>

                </children>
            </catalog>
        </menu>
        <!-- !! Menu Configuration -->

    </adminhtml>
    <!-- !! Adminhtml Configuration -->

</config>
```

**originalpricing.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <adminhtml_originalpricing_index> <!-- bulkpricing index action -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="originalpricing/adminhtml_originalpricing_assign" name="orig_assign_products" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_originalpricing_index>

</layout>
```

**Controller**

```
class Package_OriginalPricing_Adminhtml_OriginalpricingController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{


    public function indexAction ()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Catalog'))->_title($this->__('Upload CSV'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('catalog/catalog');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

**Block Assign**

```
class Package_OriginalPricing_Block_Adminhtml_Originalpricing_Assign extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $helper = Mage::helper('originalpricing');

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'originalpricing';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_originalpricing';
        $this->_mode = 'assign';
        $this->_headerText = $helper->__('Upload CSV');

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', $helper->__('Upload & Save'));

        $this->_removeButton('back');
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
class Package_OriginalPricing_Block_Adminhtml_Originalpricing_Assign_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/assign'),
                'method' => 'post',
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
            )
        );

        $helper = Mage::helper('originalpricing');

        $form->setUseContainer(true);

        $this->setForm($form);

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('assign_form', array(
            'legend' =>$helper->__('Upload CSV for Products')
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('sku_list', 'textarea', array(
            'label'     => $helper->__('SKU(s)'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'sku_list',
            'note'     => $helper->__('Enter Product SKU separated by (,) comma'),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('csv_file', 'file', array(
            'label'     => $helper->__('CSV File'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'csv_file',
            'note'     => $helper->__('Choose a .csv file to be uploaded'),
        ));

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

Everything is working fine on my local but not on live server.

Comment: @Priyank I have updated question with controllers code

Comment: Yes it's placed here `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/originalpricing.xml`

Comment: Please replace "OriginalPricing" to "Originalpricing" in all files and check

Comment: Module Name? dir name and `modules/Package_OriginalPricing.xml` all have same name...

Comment: It is case sensitive module name issue

Comment: Please change "OriginalPricing" to "Originalpricing" module name

Comment: ok let me do that

Comment: Now this error is coming `Fatal error: Class 'Package_Originalpricing_Helper_Data' not found in xxxxxxxx/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 547`.... Thing is everything works on my local but not on the live server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting answer to my question after two days of frustration and useless changes... The problem was not in my code but the the site had `Compilation` enabled from `System >> Tools >> Compilation` so I recompiled magento and suddenly all started to work. This was working on my local just because of the same reason that my local donot have `Compilation` enabled